# Could not load file or assembly SQLitePCLRaw.core

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite version 2.2.4
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 2.2.4
nuget packages on my .net core class library.

When adding my class library to Console application I am getting the following exception:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.1.12.351, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535'. The system cannot find the file specified.

My code is running on windows but will also run on Linux.

Is there any solution?

I saw a recommendation for adding 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite nuget to my console application.
but I prefer avoiding this solution.

Comment: Try adding a reference to Microsoft.Data.Sqlite package, and calling `Batteries.Init();` at the start of your program.

Comment: After adding Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and calling Batteries.Init(), I am getting new error: Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green, Version=1.1.12.351, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a84b7dcfb1391f7f'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Call Batteries.Init() solved my problem too. Took one day to find this post!
But you need this package. SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green

Answer (score 3):

i just faced same problem and doing these steps solve it

1. remove obj and bin folder
2. run `dotnet restore --force`

Comment: After this advice  it got 11987 error not a good solution. Cant go back, extremly bad "help"

Comment: Needed to reinstall Visual Studio becouse of this =(

Comment: Worked fine with Rider on Linux, although didn't fix the missing dll

Answer (score 2):

I had to Downgrade to a lower version.

```
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.6.292" />
<!--<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />-->
```

Comment: This solution worked for me (but from VS22 NuGet Packages interface). I was following some tutorial instructions. I guess that the newer dependency of `sqlite-net-pcl` does something unexpected from the time that tutorial was made.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue - something had set AutoGenerateBindingRedirects to false in my .csproj file. Reverting it back to true fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing `<assemblyBinding>` from `app.config` resolved the issue